# Do roll-on/roll-off (RORO) ships take passengers and their car?

Tags: transportation, road-trips, sea-travel, shipping, freighter-travel

I often see these massive RORO ships bringing new cars. I assume they are not always fully booked. Are there companies offering empty spots on RORO ships? To me, it seems like a great opportunity to start a road trip.

I am not talking about RORO ferries, but more of the long distance RORO ship, as portrayed [in this documentary on YouTube](http://youtu.be/_bbPJhS0byw).

[image: faust roro] source: [wikimedia](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Car_carrier_Faust_%282%29.jpg?uselang=nl)

Comment: There are RoRo ferries all around the world. Be more precise. Which regions or which routes are you interested in?

Comment: As an example, in Zeebrugge you can board a roro to Hull, in Northern England. The biggest roro ferry in the world is linking dublin and Holyhead ( google for MS ULYSSES). You see, plenty of possibilitites ...

Comment: I would go so far as to say that RoRo ferries are NOT used in the transport of new cars. New cars are transported by container ship, so that they don't have to be driven. RoRo ships are almost always bookable ferries.

Comment: @DJClayworth you are wrong there: http://www.portofantwerp.com/en/roro.

Comment: @DJClayworth also look at http://youtu.be/_bbPJhS0byw

Comment: @user3470 i am not interested in ferries, but More in more distant sollutions, as the one I just found online, see below

Comment: @DJClayworth: you've got it completely wrong. New cars are transported pretty much exclusively by RoRo ships so that they can be driven - because that's faster than unloading and handling containers. However, those are special RoRo ships quite different from ferries.

Comment: Doesn't seem too broad to me. He's asking if it's possible at all.  If it is, then presumably future questions can be about particular areas.

Comment: @andra: See if you can add a photo (don't breach anybody's copyright though!) to illustrate a RORO ship that's not a RORO ferry. Remember there's a billion of us here that can't see YouTube from the other side of the Great Firewall.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes extensive browsing remains rewarding, [at least one company](http://www.cargoshipcruises.nl/zuid-amerika.html) offers roro service for passengers and their cars. It is even from my home town to Rio. Brilliant!

Comment: Do you actually want to bring your own car? Because I cannot find information about that on that website.

Comment: @bernhard "Antwerpen-Dakar-Rio de Janeiro alleen voor passagiers met auto, camper  of motor" dutch for: only for passengers with car, camper or motorcycle.

Comment: Maybe I was looking with my nose. So for the others it means you can either or not bring a car?

Answer (score 5):

I made in September 2016 a trip on a ro-ro from Grimaldi Lines. My car was on the ro-ro and we could go in the different harbours we stopped, as far there was  enough time. We started from Antwerp: to Portbury, Setúbal, Valencia, Fos, Livorno, Civitavecchia and Salerno then took the car to Paris.

The ro-ro was transporting new cars or trucks or machines for construction.

Answer (score 2):

Beside regular car ferries carrying hundreds of private cars, there are also RoRo ferries used primarily for freight on lorries that take a few. [Grimaldi Lines](http://www.grimaldi.napoli.it/en/car_carrier_container_service.html), mentioned in earlier answers, is one of them and they definitely take private passengers with their cars on at least some of their lines.

But those are not exactly the same as the large RoRo ships used for the transport of new cars mentioned in the question. [It's also possible to travel on one of these](http://www.zylmann.de/fileadmin/zylmann/reisebeschr-eng_pdf/0311-MI_eng.pdf)… but not with your car!